# C++ and ambiguous treatment of string literals

Tags: c++, c++11

In my C++/Linux application I want to create a temp folder.

The code is very simple:

```
std::string tempFolder(mkdtemp("foo"));
```

To my surprise I received a warning message:

> warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'

Ok, as I remember C++ treats string literals as `std::string`, not a `char*`. I also know that I can avoid this message by declaring `char *` as `const char*`. So my code might look like the following:

```
const char *tpl = "foo";
std::string tempFolder(mkdtemp(tpl));
```

if not for the fact that `mkdtemp` requires `char *` and not `const char*`. So explicit casting required here and now my code should look like that:

```
const char *tpl = "foo";
std::string tempFolder(mkdtemp(const_cast<char *>(tpl)));
```

In my opinion that looks absolutely ridiculous, the code looks absolutely incomprehensible and overloaded.

So my question - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mkdtemp(3) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkdtemp.3.html) says:

> The mkdtemp() function generates a uniquely named temporary directory
> from template.  The last six characters of template must be XXXXXX
> and these are replaced with a string that makes the directory name
> unique.  The directory is then created with permissions 0700.  Since
> it will be modified, template must not be a string constant, but
> should be declared as a character array.

As you see, passing string literal to `mkdtemp()` is not allowed and you have to pass character array with string that end with `XXXXXX`.

```
char tpl[] = "fooXXXXXX";
std::string tempFolder(mkdtemp(tpl));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your belief that

> C++ treats string literals as `std::string`, not a `char*`

is wrong. String literals in C++ are really arrays of *constant* characters, ie `"foo"` is a `const char[4]`. An array decays into a pointer to its 1st element. So a pointer to such a string  must be `const char*`.

`mkdtemp()` *modifies* the string, so you can't use a string literal as the argument, you must use a non-const array.

Comment: FYI, in C++14 a string literal *can* be treated as a `std::string`, if it has the `s` suffix on it, eg: `”foo”s`, see [`std::literals::string_literals::operator””s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)